# regular expression to return the text which has 1 or more periods in between parenthesis

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a text which has 1 or more 2 period in between parenthesis.

```
K= 'Product will be hot(These cooking instructions were developed using an 100 watt microwave oven. For lower wattage ovens, up to an additional 2 minutes cooking time may be required).'
```

I'd like to extract or eliminate that entire text.I have tried

```
re.search(r'\((.*?)+\)',K).group(1)
```

and

```
K[K.find("(")+1:K.find(")")]
```

but none of them returns the text

Comment: Did you want to write "1 or 2 periods" or "1 or more periods"?

Comment: I have few texts which contains 2 or more strings with braces and 2 or more sentences with periods inside those braces. 
for example: 
'Product will be hot(These cooking instructions.  were developed using. an 100 watt microwave oven). For lower wattage ovens, (up to an additional 2 minutes.  cooking time may be required).'
So, I'd like to strip off all those strings inside the braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the following regex will remove any text between parentheses that contains one or more periods, as well as the parentheses themselves:

```
re.sub('\(.*?\.+.*\)','', K)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.sub('\(.*?\.+.*\)','', K)
'Product will be hot.'
```

To extract the text instead of removing it, use `re.findall` with the same regex:

```
>>> re.findall('\(.*?\.+.*\)', K)
['(These cooking instructions were developed using an 100 watt microwave oven. For lower wattage ovens, up to an additional 2 minutes cooking time may be required)']
```

**[Edit]**: To match if there are more than one set of braces, the following works:

```
K='Product will be hot (These cooking instructions were. developed using an 100 watt microwave oven). For lower wattage ovens (up to an additional 2 minutes. cooking time may be required).'

>>> re.findall('\(.*?\.+.*?\)', K)
['(These cooking instructions were. developed using an 100 watt microwave oven)', '(up to an additional 2 minutes. cooking time may be required)']

>>> re.sub('\(.*?\.+.*?\)', '', K)
'Product will be hot . For lower wattage ovens .'
```

Comment: What if I have more than 1 set of braces? like for example:

K='Product will be hot (These cooking instructions were. developed using an 100 watt microwave oven). For lower wattage ovens (up to an additional 2 minutes.  cooking time may be required).'

re.sub('\(.*?\.+.*\)','', K) eliminates the middle string "For lower wattage ovens" aswell. but I do need that text.

Comment: That worked.I have one more question.  how to work on regular expression in reverse direction? or i'd like to eliminate strings which precede a character ? example--"Product will be hot : These cooking instructions were developed" I'd like to eliminate string before " : " which is "product will be hot"

Answer (score 1):

You can use expression:

```
(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))
```

Try the expression live [here](https://regex101.com/r/6hHakv/1).

Use `re.findall` to find the text you are interested in.

```
import re
K = 'Product will be hot(These cooking instructions were developed using an 100 watt microwave oven. For lower wattage ovens, up to an additional 2 minutes cooking time may be required).'
print(re.findall(r'(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))',K))
```

Prints:

```
['These cooking instructions were developed using an 100 watt microwave oven. For lower wattage ovens, up to an additional 2 minutes cooking time may be required']
```

---

Alternatively wrap the character set in a capturing group:

```
import re
K = 'Product will be hot(These cooking instructions were developed using an 100 watt microwave oven. For lower wattage ovens, up to an additional 2 minutes cooking time may be required).'
print(re.search(r'(?<=\()([^()]*)(?=\))',K).group(1))
```

Prints:

```
These cooking instructions were developed using an 100 watt microwave oven. For lower wattage ovens, up to an additional 2 minutes cooking time may be required
```

Comment: What if I have more than 1 set of braces? like for example: 

K='Product will be hot (These cooking instructions were. developed using an 100 watt microwave oven). For lower wattage ovens (up to an additional 2 minutes. cooking time may be required).'

Comment: yes. but it did not give me the result what i wanted but Sacul's idea above worked . Anyway I have one more problem. how to work on regular expression in reverse direction? or i'd like to eliminate strings which precede a character ?
example--"Product will be hot : These cooking instructions were developed"
I'd like to eliminate string before " : " which is "product will be hot"

Comment: My solution does what you asked for, it matches contents within both strings. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/DeqzVc/4) (link). In that case you can use : `K = "Product will be hot : These cooking instructions were developed"

print(re.sub(r'[^:]*(?=:)','',K))
` it you want to retain the `:` too.

Answer (score 1):

This takes care that no substitution is done if more than two periods are in the parentheses, and also, that not two parenthesized sections get merged thus eliminating text between them:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\(([^.(]*\.){1,2}[^.()]*\)',"",K)
'Product will be hot.'
```

If you also want to remove parenthesized sections with more than two periods, you may simply replace `{1,2}` by a `+`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\(([^.(]*\.)+[^.()]*\)',"",K)
```